# tikz includegraphics within style

Tags: tikz-styles

I searching for a solution to define a node style whish includes a png-picture.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   [
     PIC/.style n args = {1}
                         {align=center,
                          label={center:
                                 \includegraphics[scale=0.01,rotate=#1]{picture.png}
                                }
                         }
   ]

   \node[PIC={60}] (f) at (0,0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried some other versions with \node but I have no real idea...

Hope you can help - thanks.

---

Additionally an example with two parameters:

```
[...
PT/.style n args = {2}{circle,draw,align=center,
                       inner sep=1pt,label={#1:#2}}]
...
\node[PT={below}{1}] (PT) at (0,0) {};
```

This will fully pass the arguments. If I set these:

```
[...
PT/.style n args = {1}{circle,draw,align=center,
                       inner sep=1pt,label={#1:2}}]
...
\node[PT={below}] (PT) at (0,0) {};
```

it only pass `b` instead of `below`

---

Thanks to Jesse!
I don't know what is better. To define a `token` or do some crasy things like this:

Var 1

```
[...
PT/.style n args = {1}{circle,draw,align=center,
                       inner sep=1pt,label={#1:2}}]
...
\node[PT={below}\ ] (PT) at (0,0) {};
```

Var 2

```
[...
PT/.style n args = {1}{circle,draw,align=center,
                       inner sep=1pt,label={#1:2}}]
...
\node[PT={below}{} ] (PT) at (0,0) {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that changing `rotate` into `angle` makes the error gone. Please check the following website for `includggraphics` commands http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\ang{60}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[PIC/.style n args ={1}{align=center,label={center:
\includegraphics[scale=0.25,angle=#1]{example-image-a}
}}
]
 \node[PIC={\ang}] (f) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** The OP observes that only the first character was passed to the argument (ie., only 6, not 60, was passed to the argument.)  A remedy is to define a command called `\ang` via `\def\ang{60}`, then pass this `\ang` to the argument, as shown above in the the code. Same idea applies to the follow-up by the OP. The image is newly compiled result.

Comment: Yes - I was blind. This goes...
In this case there are an bug: It passes only the letter. (In your case 60->6) What I have to add to get the whole value.

Comment: @Alex44 -- You are right. Please see my update where \ang=60 is defined at preamble and use \ang to replace 60 in the node option.

Comment: Thanks - now it fully goes. The definition of an variable is a bit hacky ;)
I don't understand, why it pass right with two arguments but not with one...

Comment: @Alex44 -- After a macro definition, \abc with the backlash becomes a unit, also known as a `token`.